# django form multiple fields dynamically

Tags: python, django, forms, model

So I want to create a member form with Education part that will contain 3 elements:

Foreign Key to Academic_Background (which has High School, BC degree, master degree, etc..),

Charfield - Name of school

Charfield - Field of studies

No problem doing one, or two... but how can I make several  "Education" fields (by adding a button of "Add another" and using JS&Jquery to display the new Education to the user.

What should I put in my Model, and in my Form? and how will it be saved in the DB?

It seems like something that probably happened to someone before, yet I couldn't find a solution for that...

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: Have you read about this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

i did this without using django forms .. just using html forms to upload multiple as many as user wishes..

this is my template.html file which has normal form without any input file field initially

the js method adds a new input file field to the form when clicked on "add new item" href

```
<form action="{{request.path}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
        {%csrf_token%}
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{request.POST.name}}" placeholder="Person Name"/>
  <input type="text" name="categorie" id="categorie" value="{{request.POST.categorie}}" placeholder="Categorie"/>

  <div class="file_inputs" id="file_inputs"> 
  <!-- <-- field where im adding multiple files initially empty -->

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>

<!-- link to add new file input box when clicked on it -->
<a href="#" onClick="addformelement()" >add new item</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
// method to add an file input box when clicked on add new item link
function addformelement(){
        a = document.getElementById('file_inputs')

        divx=document.createElement('div')
        divx.class='file_inputs'

         x=document.createElement('input');
         x.type='file';
         x.name='docfile';

         divx.appendChild(x);
         a.appendChild(divx) ;
}
</script>
```

and in views i did this

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
                name_instance = get_name_instance(request)
                if(name_instance == -1):
                        return HttpResponse("Error - Check Server logs")

                for f in request.FILES.getlist('docfile'):
                        # do your logic for each file f
                        # as f.name to get filename ...
```

all my fileinputs have the same id as docfile ...

so in my views i called getlist('docfile')

you can do the same with normal data like

```
request.POST.getlist('idname')
```